# Changed the domain on windows 7 machine. How can I revert back to original Domain name?

Tags: windows, networking, authentication, dns

My windows 7 laptop was joined to a domain named TestDomain1. Then I brought my laptop to a new office location, and was still able to log in to the Domain TestDomain1. But I changed the laptop to a new Domain that the particular office is using, let's say TestDomain2, and I was able to connect to the TestDomain2. But the problem is, I want to go back and set the laptop in using the TestDomain1 again, but it won't let me because I am not connected with TestDomain1 network.

Question:

1. I was using TestDomain1\TestUser to log in before. But now since I changed the domain of the laptop to TestDomain2 I cannot log in to my previous account, is there a way that I can login again to TestDomain1\TestUser?
2. Can I change the domain back to TestDomain1 even without physically connected to the network for the TestDomain1?

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Initialy your laptop was a  member of TestDomain1. Then it is possible to log on to the domain even if you are not able to contact the domain controller, bcoz previous logon cache will be there, refer the below mentioned pages

```
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755473%28WS.10%29.aspx
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172931
```

then you moved to a different domain TestDomain2, So if you want to move back to TestDomain1 again, you need to have connection with the first domain controller.